# how to multiply value with two const array in React js

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I am new to react js trying to do multiplication using two different const array

```
export const transactions = [
  {
    sequence_number: 3,
    book_date: "2020-01-02",
    account_id: 1,
    value: 150123,
  },
  {
    sequence_number: 3,
    book_date: "2020-03-02",
    account_id: 2,
    value: 192842,
  },
  {
    sequence_number: 2,
    book_date: "2020-04-03",
    account_id: 2,
    value: 142592,
  },
];

export const monthly_rates = [
  {
    effective_date: "2020-01-01",
    multiplier: 0.9,
  },
  {
    effective_date: "2020-02-01",
    multiplier: 1.3,
  },
  {
    effective_date: "2020-03-03",
    multiplier: 1.5,
  },
  {
    effective_date: "2020-04-01",
    multiplier: 1.3,
  },
  {
    effective_date: "2020-05-15",
    multiplier: 1.5,
  },
];
```

I want to total value with multiplication suppose for

```
{
    sequence_number: 2,
    book_date: "2020-04-03",
    account_id: 2,
    value: 142592,
  },
```

We see that the rate that was effective on 2020-04-03 is 1.3
value  = multiplier * value = 1.3 * 142592

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, you want to get the multiplier by comparing the effective_date and book_date, after that you want to calculate value of the transaction times multiplier of that rate's multiplier.

For example if book_date is: 2020-04-01

- And if there is a rate with an effective_date of something prior to
  2020-04-1, that is the rate that we are looking for. If there are
  multiple of them, we want the latest one.

Correct me if i am wrong please.

I created and tested this function and it seems to work:

```js
const multiplyByTransaction = (transaction) => {
  let multiplier = null;

  // sort in ascending order in case they are not sorted.
  // you can remove the sort() if you have them sorted already
  const sorted_rates = monthly_rates.sort(
    (a, b) => a.effective_date - b.effective_date
  );

  for (let index = 0; index < sorted_rates.length; index++) {
    if (
      Date.parse(transaction.book_date) <
      Date.parse(sorted_rates[index].effective_date)
    ) {
      multiplier = sorted_rates[index > 0 ? --index : index].multiplier;
      break;
    }
  }

  // this means that there isn't any effective_date that is greater than book_date of the transaction
  // so we assign the latest rate's multiplier to our multiplier
  if (!multiplier) {
    multiplier = sorted_rates[sorted_rates.length - 1].multiplier;
  }

console.log(
    `Calculating: Multiplier => ${multiplier} * value => ${
      transaction.value
    } = ${multiplier * transaction.value}`
  );
  return multiplier * transaction.value;
};

multiplyByTransaction(transactions[1]) // will log: Calculating: Multiplier => 1.3 * value => 192842 = 250694.6
```

Hope it helps!